# Which way will have better performance - Filter/Order results with sql query or php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

Recently I tried new way to filter/order SQL queries: instead filter / order the results in SQL query I pull all data I need "as is" then doing the filters / orders with php code.

For example : I want only events with name like "test" order by Date .

Table struct :

```
id     eventDate     eventName
```

New way :

```
$query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "SELECT `eventDate`, `eventName` FROM `tablename` WHERE `id`='X' ");
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query))array_push($this->events,$data);
```

Then I'm using `array_fillter` and `usort` /`array_multisort` and `array_values`  in php...

Old way :

```
$query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], "SELECT `eventDate`, `eventName` FROM `tablename` WHERE `id`='X' AND (`eventName` LIKE '%test%') ORDER by `eventDate` DESC ") ;
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query))array_push($this->events,$data);
```

So what is better ? **complex sql queries** or **pull all the data "as is" then make the filters and orders in php** ?

The above example is very simple. I'm talking about much more complex filtering...

Please answer if you are absolutely sure !

Thanks :)

Comment: Why not let databases do what they're good at and optimised for (filtering and ordering), and let PHP do what it's good at? If your database is properly structured and indexed, then it's vastly superior to PHP for filtering and ordering data

Comment: Depending on the size of your result set, there is another alternative: push the unsorted data to the client and use JavaScript to do the sorting client-side.

Comment: Your queries do not do what the question in your text is.  The queries filter by `id`.  Presumably that should also be part of the conditions in the second paragraph.

Comment: A row that is discarded in PHP needs to be read from the storage in MySQL, sent through the net, stored in RAM on the PHP side. All these operations use resources and take time. The transfer and the storage on the PHP side and many times even the reading from storage on the MySQL side can be avoided by filtering in MySQL. The result is faster code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer will depend on a number of factors, including:

1. The size of your database
2. How the database is indexed
3. The size of the result row

### Pros for filtering with PHP:

- Less Complex SQL Queries
- Potentially Simpler Code

### Cons for filtering with PHP:

- Higher RAM usage, and with a large dataset, this can be a real deal breaker
- Slower (Unless you have a table which is not indexed properly)

### Pros for filtering with SQL:

- Typically much faster, especially on properly indexed tables
- Less RAM Usage
- Less Data to Parse

### Cons for filtering with SQL:

- SQL queries can become unreadable if taken too far
- Moving more logic to the query can make database interpretability more challenging (mySQL, SQLite, etc.)

Your milage my vary. Everyone has their own opinions, but in my personal experience, I've found that using native SQL filtering is typically the better choice. Remember the ultimate goal should be clean, maintainable code. And using an [SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) goes a long way in making SQL more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Logicaly mysql will be faster in all cases (avoid data transfer to php, mysql is written on c++), but it is the subject to test.

True power reveals with usage of indexes. In your case you use "like '%value%'" which disables index. But in easily solvable with fulltext index. With MySql 5.6 Fulltext indexes supported in InnoDB engine as well.